# Help me decipher the notation in the given definition

Tags: probability, expected-value, mean

I was going through a book on statistics and I came across this definition of expectation.

Let $X : \Omega \rightarrow D  $, be a discrete random variable and let $\phi : D \rightarrow {\rm I\!R}$ The expectation of $\phi(X)$ is defined as:

$\textbf{E}(\phi(X)) = \sum_{i\epsilon D} \phi(i) \textbf{P}\{X = i\}$

Can you guys please tell me what kind of function is $\phi$ here?

Here, $D$ is a set of real numbers.

Comment: It’s a transformation of the random variable, meaning that if you want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$, you can do so without having to calculate $X^2$ (or $\sin(X)$ or $e^X$, etc).

Comment: $\phi$ is, as stated, literally any such function (without exception).